# Fixed horizontal spacing from bigger of the two labels

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, xib

I have five labels in a xib, as in the attached image (link below), which shows the constraints as well. Labels 1, 2, 3 and 4 have fixed height constraints with a constant value of 11, and these four labels are set to adjust size with containing text, so their widths vary with the texts they contain.  Label 1 and 2 have a fixed leading margin from the superview, Label 1 has a constraint dictating fixed top margin from superview and label 2 has a constraint dictating fixed bottom margin from superview. Labels 3 and 4 have their x and y positions pinned in the same way. The main label has constraints causing its top and bottom to stick to those of superview so that its height is same as that of the superview. Now, I want this main label to have a fixed leading horizontal spacing of 8 points from the wider of label 1 and 2, and fixed trailing horizontal spacing of 8 points from the wider of label 3 and label 4. How can this be accomplished with addition of horizontal space constraints from the nearest neighbor?
[image: link to image]

Answer (score 0):

Hah, tricky.

## 8 new constraints:

1. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 1

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Equal
   - Priority: 750
2. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 1

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Greater Than or Equal
   - Priority: 1000

**SPOILER: this pattern repeats for the rest of the labels**

3. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 2

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Equal
   - Priority: 750
4. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 2

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Greater Than or Equal
   - Priority: 1000
5. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 3

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Equal
   - Priority: 750
6. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 3

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Greater Than or Equal
   - Priority: 1000
7. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 4

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Equal
   - Priority: 750
8. Horizontal constraint from main label to label 4

   - Constant: 8
   - Relation: Greater Than or Equal
   - Priority: 1000

## Why? How?

The first constraint says, "When possible, please put exactly 8 pt between main label and label 1". This ensures your main label tries to expand to the largest size possible.

The second constraint says, "NEVER allow main label to encroach past the 8 pt horizontal space before label 1". This keeps main label from ever overlapping label 1, even if label 2 is small enough to pull it that way.